# Connecting Spring Boot Docker container to MongoDB docker container

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am trying to connect a spring boot docker container to a mongodb docker container. While developing Spring Boot app, I used a MongoDB docker container with port 27017 mapped to the host machine's 27017 port with `docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo:3.4`. When development finished, I containerized the spring app, but containerized spring app could not connect to the mongodb container. I know the problem is spring app is looking for mongodb at localhost. My question is how should I modify the app so that instead of looking for mongodb at localhost, it uses mongodb containers's address?

My database connections are handled with class below:

```
public class DB {
private final Datastore datastore;
private Morphia morphia;

/**
 * Constructor for creating database instance
 */
public DB() {
    morphia = new Morphia();
    morphia.mapPackage("users");
    datastore =
            morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test");
    datastore.ensureIndexes();
}

/**
 * Inserts given user to the database
 *
 * @param u a newly created user.
 */
public void addUser(User u) {
    datastore.save(u);
}

/**
 * Fetches and prints all documents in database
 *
 * @return json array of all documents in database
 */
public String getUsers() {
    final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class);
    final List<User> employees = query.asList();

    return objToJson(employees);
}

/**
 * Returns the user with the specified ID.
 *
 * @param userID is the ID of the document in database
 * @return document in json format
 */
public String getUser(ObjectId userID) {
    final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class)
            .field("id").equal(userID);

    final List<User> employees = query.asList();
    return objToJson(employees);
}

/**
 * Deletes the document with the given ID from database.
 *
 * @param userID is the ID of the document to be removed
 */
public void removeUser(ObjectId userID) {
    final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class)
            .field("id").equal(userID);
    datastore.delete(query);
}

/**
 * Deletes all documents from database.
 */
public void removeUsers() {
    final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class);
    datastore.delete(query);
}

/**
 * Updates the fields of the document with given ID.
 *
 * @param userID  is the ID of the document to be updated
 * @param newUser contains the new fields
 * @return results of the update in json format
 */
public String updateUser(ObjectId userID, User newUser) {
    final Query<User> query = datastore.createQuery(User.class)
            .field("id").equal(userID);
    final UpdateOperations<User> updateOperations = datastore.createUpdateOperations(User.class);

    if (newUser.getFirst_name() != null) {
        String newName = newUser.getFirst_name();
        updateOperations.set("first_name", newName);
    }

    if (newUser.getLast_name() != null) {
        String newLastName = newUser.getLast_name();
        updateOperations.set("last_name", newLastName);
    }

    if (newUser.getSalary() != 0) {
        int newSalary = newUser.getSalary();
        updateOperations.set("salary", newSalary);
    }

    final UpdateResults results = datastore.update(query, updateOperations);
    return results.toString();

}

/**
 * Translate object lists to the json array.
 *
 * @param query is the list of the user objects
 * @return json array of the given users
 */
private String objToJson(List<User> query) {
    List<String> attsToRemove = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"className"});

    List<DBObject> dbObjList = new ArrayList<>(query.size());
    DBObject dbObj;
    for (Object obj : query) {
        dbObj = morphia.toDBObject(obj);
        for (int i = 0; i < attsToRemove.size(); i++) {
            dbObj.removeField(attsToRemove.get(i));
        }
        dbObjList.add(dbObj);
    }
    String json = JSON.serialize(dbObjList);
    return json;
}
```

Here is my spring boot controller

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

DB mongodb = new DB();

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "Greetings from Spring Boot";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{user_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUser(@PathVariable("user_id") ObjectId userID) {
    return mongodb.getUser(userID);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getUsers() {
    return mongodb.getUsers();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void createUser(@RequestBody User u) {
    try {
        mongodb.addUser(u);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteUsers() {
    try {
        mongodb.removeUsers();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{user-id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteUser(@PathVariable("user-id") ObjectId userID) {
    try {
        mongodb.removeUser(userID);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/{user-id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String updateUser(@PathVariable("user-id") ObjectId userID, @RequestBody User u) {
    return mongodb.updateUser(userID, u);
}
```

And here is my Dockerfile:

`FROM frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim
VOLUME /tmp
ADD demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 27017
EXPOSE 8080
RUN sh -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /app.jar" ]`

I read the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27988888/docker-linking-spring-boot-container-with-mongo-db-container) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456083/spring-boot-with-mongodb-on-docker). Also read through couple of tutorials but I couldn't fit any of these solutions to my code. In my code, where should I change?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is that your containers are not in the same network. I guess you can find a working example by this [How to run Spring Boot and MongoDB in Docker containe](http://dev-pages.info/how-to-run-spring-boot-and-mongodb-in-docker-container/). Here is a short extract:

1. `docker network create spring_demo_net`  create a network
2. `docker run --name spring-demo-mongo --network=spring_demo_net -v /home/ubuntu/mongo-data:/data/db -d mongo` start a mongo container
3. Modify mongo host in application properties as following `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://spring-demo-mongo/YOUR_DB` here **spring-demo-mongo** is the name of container that you created on step 1.

*Since you are not using SpringData repositories it will not work so you need to create a MongoClient by explicitly passing host and port:*

```
MongoClient mongoClient2 = new MongoClient("spring-demo-mongo", 27017);
```

4. `docker build --tag=spring-demo-1.0` build your docker image  with tag
5. `docker run -d --name spring-demo --network=spring_demo_net -p 8080:8080  spring-demo-1.0` start your docker image

Comment: I did the things you said but didn't work. Spring Boot logs says: 
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

And mongodb logs stays as followed:
2017-06-08T15:33:40.094+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017

Comment: @FatihBarmanbay I guess the issue is that you have not configured host in your mongo client, since you don't use SringData the property that I mentioned will not work for you.

Comment: I changed the line:
`datastore =
            morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), "test");`
with 
`datastore =
            morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient("spring-demo-mongo", 27017), "test");`
But when I try to build the project with `mvn clean install` I get a error that says:

_com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: spring-demo-mongo_
_Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spring-demo-mongo_

Comment: @FatihBarmanbay do you have some unit tests that running during the maven build? If so please disable them by running "mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true" Because you are trying to access your mongo host outside the docker container